# Find the value in intervals arrays in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the follow df:

```
state   interval      limits       cep_ori
PA     >=5, <=10      >10    [{111, 222}, {333, 444}]
SP     >=6, <=10      <8     [{333, 444}, {555, 666}]
```

Follow the Schema:

```
root
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- interval: string (nullable = true)
 |-- limits: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cep_ori: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- inicial: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- final: integer (nullable = true)
```

I have another df (df2):

```
seller_id  cep
12222      114
33332      43
33344      338
```

I need to inner join if the field 'cep' contains in any interval (inicial, final) of field 'cep_ori'.

So, the df_final I need:

```
state   interval      limits       cep_ori              seller_id
PA     >=5, <=10      >10    [{111, 222}, {333, 444}]     12222
PA     >=5, <=10      >10    [{111, 222}, {333, 444}]     33344
SP     >=6, <=10      <8     [{333, 444}, {555, 666}]     33344
```

I tried:

```
df.filter(sf.size(sf.array_intersect(df.cep_ori.inicial, sf.array(df2.cep)) != 0))
.filter(sf.size(sf.array_intersect(df.cep_ori.final,sf.array(df2.cep)) != 0))
```

But, don't worked.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert cep_ori column into array which includes all integer values in mentioned range by using `transform` and `sequence` functions.
Then join with second dataframe and filter the values where cep exists in the range specified in cep_ori column.

```
df1 = # first dataframe
df1=df1.withColumn("cep_ori_array", expr("flatten(transform(cep_ori, x->sequence(x.inicial,x.final)))"))
df2=spark.createDataFrame([(12222,114),(33332,43),(33344,338)],['seller_id', 'cep'])
df2.join(df1).where(array_contains("cep_ori_array", col("cep").cast("bigint"))==True).drop("cep_ori_array").show(truncate=False)

+---------+---+------------------------+---------+------+-----+
|seller_id|cep|cep_ori                 |interval |limits|state|
+---------+---+------------------------+---------+------+-----+
|12222    |114|[{222, 111}, {444, 333}]|>=5, <=10|>10   |PA   |
|33344    |338|[{222, 111}, {444, 333}]|>=5, <=10|>10   |PA   |
|33344    |338|[{444, 333}, {666, 555}]|>=6, <=10|<8    |SP   |
+---------+---+------------------------+---------+------+-----+
```

Comment: One doubt, if I have for example 222 or 111 in field 'cep' in any seller_id to appear in inner join ? In anothers words, the same value there is in 'inicial' or 'final' it's work in inner join?

Comment: It should work as sequence function is inclusive.